# Trouble installing any program on windows

Tags: windows-7, installation

I am not able to install any program on my system. Below is the pop-up i have been receiving.

Unable to find a volume for file extraction. Please verify that you have proper permissions?

What should i do? 
It happens whenever  try to install a program on my system.

Comment: Hello, try with the option "Run as an administrator" (click right with the mouse...)

Comment: hey, i tried doing it as well. Didn't help. :o

Comment: it says that - can not create temp folder archive

Comment: I think that you should check the permissionthe program is going to use. Is the computer at work?